# Can I use a query by itself as a filter in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I know I didn't make it clear in the question title. Let me explain.

Say I have a Table `SOURCE_TABLE` with 1 column that looks like this:

```
Filter 
------------------|
Name='John' 
Surname = 'Smith' 
Age = '25'
```

And I want to use this table as a filter. Like below:

```
SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE (SELECT FILTER FROM SOURCE_TABLE)
```

I heard maybe evaluate function could help me but to be honest I couldn't understand how.

Do you know any method that I can use a column as my filter source like above?

---

Edit1:

```
DECLARE 
    my_filter VARCHAR2(100); 
    my_query VARCHAR2(500); 
BEGIN 
    my_query := 'SELECT FILTER FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM=1'; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_query INTO my_filter; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM TARGET_TABLE WHERE '|| my_filter; 
END;
```

[@Sujitmohanty30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950437/can-i-use-a-query-by-itself-as-a-filter-in-pl-sql#comment113085371_63950437) I have come up with the above after learning `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. But there is a problem I stumble upon. This needs to be dynamic regarding to the end result and i want to see the result of the select query at the end.

Comment: This type of requirement need the SQL to be build dynamically and you can achieve the same in oracle using `execute immediate`. Are you okay with it ?

Comment: There is also xmltable/xmlquery solution. I'll post it when I get home

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have these 2 tables:

```sql
create table TARGET_TABLE(name varchar2(30), surname varchar2(30));
insert into TARGET_TABLE(name,surname) values ('John', 'Doe');
insert into TARGET_TABLE(name,surname) values ('Ann', 'Smith');
insert into TARGET_TABLE(name,surname) values ('Steven', 'Feuerstein');
insert into TARGET_TABLE(name,surname) values ('Steven', 'King');
commit;

create table SOURCE_TABLE(filter) as
select q'[name='John']' from dual union all
select q'[name='Ann']' from dual union all
select q'[name='Steven' and surname='King']' from dual union all
select q'[surname='Feuerstein']' from dual;
```

Then you can use xmltable and dbms_xmlgen.getXMLtype to get such rows dynamically:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72abdf18b149cf30882cb4e1736c9c33

```sql
select *
from SOURCE_TABLE
    , xmltable(
        '/ROWSET/ROW'
        passing dbms_xmlgen.getXMLtype('select * from TARGET_TABLE where '|| SOURCE_TABLE.filter)
        columns 
          name    varchar2(30) path 'NAME',
          surname varchar2(30) path 'SURNAME'
        ) x;
```

Results:

```
FILTER                           NAME                           SURNAME
-------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
name='John'                      John                           Doe
name='Ann'                       Ann                            Smith
name='Steven' and surname='King' Steven                         King
surname='Feuerstein'             Steven                         Feuerstein
```

Comment: That's actually a big part of my question. However, there is some more. See, i don't have just 2 parameters like 'name' and 'surname'. I have many and i don't want to hardcode it. similarly, i don't have just 2 columns in my target_table. there are more than 200 and counting. Is there a way to make it that dynamic?

Comment: @eoeroglu You can use PTF (Polymorphic table functions): 1. https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c 2. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HQLG3NW48RWDODS8J3P8V5AYR.html